# Single command at the beginning of my Latex document that induces linebreaks?

Tags: line-breaking

Currently I have to do something like this:

In addition, the \linebreak knowledge retention rate of the students also increased by almost 12% when questions were reintroduced.

Otherwise knowledge would be separated in the pdf like: knowl-edge.

Any help, please?

Comment: That's the standard hyphenation, according to [Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/knowledge). The UK English hyphenation seems to be `know-ledge`, but then you should declare you're using UK English with the suitable option to `babel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample document:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\begin{document}

Some words words words.
In addition, the knowledge retention rate of the students also
increased by almost 12\% when questions were reintroduced.

\end{document}
```

The `twocolumn` option is meant to show the line break without making too long sentences.

[image]

According to the [Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/knowledge), `knowl-edge` is the correct hyphenation in American English.

The British English hyphenation seems to differ (it's very common):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}

\begin{document}

Some words words words.
In addition, the knowledge retention rate of the students also
increased by almost 12\% when questions were reintroduced.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now it's up to you to decide between US or UK English hyphenation rules and spelling. If you want to override the hyphenation and still use US English, add

```
\hyphenation{know-ledge}
```

to your document preamble.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\hyphenation{know-ledge}

\begin{document}

Some words words words. 
In addition, the knowledge retention rate of the students also 
increased by almost 12\% when questions were reintroduced.

\end{document}
```

The output will be the same as in the second picture above.

Comment: Thank you for this. This does help with the hyphenation type as I am using UK-English. However, what I actually wanted to know was if there existed a line break command that I can insert at the beginning of the document so that there would be no hyphenations in my pdf at all.  I want the document to know that instead of hyphenating a word, it should insert a line break and force that word unto the next line, so that I don't have to insert \linebreak before each such instance. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @ZaanWELLIES96 No hyphenation at all? It's surely possible, but will make the document full of white holes. Do `\raggedright` at the beginning, then, because justification without hyphenation is essentially impossible, if you want to have decent typesetting.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will check this out and then decide whether it is a good call or not. Kind regards.